# CSS breaking measured window size

Tags: html, css, layout, web

I'm styling a blog run on Jekyll (-v 0.12.1) and running into a problem where measuring the window size of index.html is 1103px and then the same unchanged window on a post page would measure 1088px (using XScope).

This is causing the header logo to "shift" a few pixels from page to page, and I can't for the life of me figure out why- except that setting a margin/width would reduce the window measurement on the post page (but not on the index).

### post.html

```
---
layout: default
---

<section class="post">
  <div class="container">
    <article class="centered">

      <header class="post-header">
        <div class="post-meta">{{ page.date | date: "%b %d, %Y" }}</div>
        <h1 class="post-title">
          <a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
        </h1>
      </header>

      <div class="post-body">

      {{ content }}

      </div>

    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

### post css

```
.post {
  margin-top: 2rem;

  .post-header {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;

    .post-meta {
      margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
      font-family: $font-family-sans;
      color: $light-text-color;
      font-weight: 300;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .post-title {
      @extend .beta;
      @extend %hN;
      font-family: "proxima-nova-alt-ext-cond", sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
} 

.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 63em;
}

.centered {
    max-width: 31rem; 
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: is there a scrollbar on the page? one might be including the width of scrollbar and another excluding it

Comment: I think its a question of the used box model. Try setting `box-sizing: border-box;` for your containers. Then padding and margin have no impact on the defined width. Add `-moz-` or `-webkit-`prefix if required by your browser.

Comment: @JakeZeitz oh god I feel awfully stupid now (the curse of a tall monitor)--a thousand thanks and a lesson learned. Are there any tricks to factor out the scrollbar in the window width?